# EDMX file does not update Stored procedure

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2013, entity-framework-5, edmx

When I am updating my `.EDMX` file with option "Update Model From Database" at that time I am able to select new stored procedures but after model is updated I am getting only `tables` and not `stored procedures / functions`.

Only tables get updated & not stored procedure or functions.

Comment: Which version of Visual Studio and the .NET framework and Entity Framework are you using?

Comment: @marc_s I am using VS 2013 & EF 5.0

Comment: You need to import SP as function. There is an option of function import click on that and you will see your SPs.

Comment: @MairajAhmad I have checked all the options.

Comment: @Rahul In 'Model Browser' window, under 'Function Import', find the stored procedure you want to update, right click and click edit, under 'returns a collection of' area, Click update button  and click column information button then the Stored procedure will update